# Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'Ref<boolean>'

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3

I have the following code:

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
    <button @click="login">Login</button>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { loggedIn } from '../state'
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            loggedIn,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            this.loggedIn = true
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

```js
// state.ts
import { reactive, ref } from 'vue'

export const loggedIn = ref(true)
```

The code above has a compilation error (which shows both in VS Code and from `vue-cli-service serve`)

```
TS2322: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'Ref<boolean>'.

  >  |             this.loggedIn = true
```

I'm pretty sure that's how I'm supposed to do it, so I'm not sure why I'm getting an error. I can change the code to this and the error goes away: `this.loggedIn.value = true` But I'm pretty sure that's not how its supposed to work, and I get this runtime error:

```
Cannot create property 'value' on boolean 'false'
```

Why am I getting this compilation error in my original code?

Comment: Try `loggedIn = ref<boolean>(true)`

Comment: Hope this helps and appreciate an upvote thanks

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-cdn-ok40d

**App.vue**

```
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="login">Login</button>
    <div>{{ data }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { loggedIn } from "./state";

export default {
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    const data = loggedIn();
    const login = () => (data.value = !data.value);
    return { data, login };
  },
};
</script>
```

**State.ts**

```
import { ref } from "vue";

export const loggedIn = () => ref(false);
```

**Main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

So the thing is, if we use the composition API, we should use the `setup()` method to setup out data and methods.

Since ref uses the .value to change the value, we don't need `reactive`.

Reactive is used for `object` values - which it will add a `Proxy` to watch over the key/values of the object.

In this case, we should use ref.